# Hand gesture recognition using haar training and hidden Markov model

Tags: opencv, gesture-recognition, haar-wavelet

I am doing a project on hand gesture recognition using hidden markov model (HMM). For the detection of the hand, I have narrowed down to two techniques: haar training and skin color based detection. Haar training looks more promising, could you please tell how do I start off with the detection part, I already have the xml file of the left hand.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with OpenCv, but spotted this project might be of use: [EHCI](http://code.google.com/p/ehci/wiki/HandTracking)

[image: HandVu Preview]